# Error in trasforming a model in a gallery

Tags: asset

a newby question.

I downloaded a model ( https://polyhaven.com/a/modular_fort_01 ) containing a lot of objects.

I'm trying to convert everything in assets to create a library.

But when I mark objects as assets seems that something is missing and the asset is represented with strange colors.
[image]

What is the correct method to transform an object in an asset?